# make VBA form only read one workbook when other workbooks are open

Tags: vba, forms, excel

I'm new here, I've read the rules, but please inform/forgive me if I have missed anything or posted incorrectly.

Now, to my problem:

I have created my first form in Visual Basic that has allowed me to create a searchable and editable database.

Upon allowing colleagues to test the form, I quickly released that they cannot use any of their other Excel workbooks that they have open (The other workbooks are not related in any way to my workbook/form).

After some researching, I found that I can add (vbmodeless) to the button that opens the form. This then allows the team to flick between the form and use other workbooks to look at other information and then go back onto the form.

The only problem I have now, is that when they go back to the form, it reads an error in the macros, because its trying to use the macros on another workbook and not my workbook.

In short, is there any way you can use (vbmodeless), but lock the forms Macros to my specific workbook?

If anyone can solve this riddle, they will be my best friend. I'm aiming to have this ready for its presentation next week on the 6th of March.

Thank you.

Comment: In your userform codes, you need to specify the workbook.  Something like `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")` for example.  I'm guessing a workbook is never specified, so Excel is defaulting to `ActiveWorkbook`.  Hard to say more without seeing some code.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's say like tigeravatar, you haven't declared a workbook :

```
Dim ws As Workbook
ws = ActiveWorkbook
'instead of
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3") = 5 'for example
'you would have
ws.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3") = 5
```

You can also work with the sheets itself, but you'll have to use parameters and search each :

```
Dim ws As Workbook
Dim sh, SpecificSheet1, SpecificSheet2 as Object 'To manipulate sheets
Dim Name_Sheet1, Name_Sheet2 As String 

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook
Name_Sheet1= "Sheet1"
Name_Sheet2= "Sheet2"

For Each sh In Sheets
    If InStr(sh.Name, Name_Sheet1) = 1 Then
        Set SpecificSheet1 = sh
    ElseIf InStr(sh.Name, Nom_Ref_Donnees) = 1 Then
        Set SpecificSheet2 = sh
    End If
Next
```

'Instead of :

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3") = 5 'for example
```

'You would use :

```
SpecificSheet1.Range("A3") = 5
```

According to your way of using subs, theses both solutions may need to use Public declaration of theses objects :

```
Option Explicit
Public ws As Workbook
Public SpecificSheet1, SpecificSheet2 as Object 'To manipulate sheets

Sub yoursub()
    Dim sh, SpecificSheet1, SpecificSheet2 as Object 'To manipulate sheets
    Dim Name_Sheet1, Name_Sheet2 As String         

    If (IsEmpty(ws)) Then
        Set ws = ActiveWorkbook
    Else
        ws.activate
    End If
    Name_Sheet1= "Sheet1"
    Name_Sheet2= "Sheet2"

    For Each sh In Sheets
        If InStr(sh.Name, Name_Sheet1) = 1 Then
            Set SpecificSheet1 = sh
        ElseIf InStr(sh.Name, Nom_Ref_Donnees) = 1 Then
            Set SpecificSheet2 = sh
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Your `For Each sh In Sheets` still doesn't use the specified workbook, so that code would also default to `ActiveWorkbook` instead of the specified.  You're also setting `ws` to `ActiveWorkbook`, so even if you had specified `ws.Sheets` it would still use the `ActiveWorkbook` which is what the suspected problem is, so if OP used this proposed solution, the problem would still exist.

Comment: I agree if the sub is called while in another file. But that sub is supposed to be called with the launch of the form. The rest of the subs or codes may be using theses Public variables, am I right ?

Comment: If the public variables are used, yes that would be correct.  However, you are overwriting the public variable to point to `ActiveWorkbook` each time `yoursub` is called, so it will always point to whatever the active workbook is, instead of sticking with a single assigned workbook.  Best bet would be to put the public workbook variable assignment in `Userform_Initialize` (and not in `yoursub`), and then always precede Sheets with ws, such as using `For Each sh In ws.Sheets` instead of just `For Each sh In Sheets`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but searching [this information](http://silkyroad.developpez.com/VBA/UserForm/), I do not understand how "Userform_Initialize" could get the ActiveWorkbook selection. I don't know this at all. Still, in case there would be a multiple call problem with my code, I added a test on the ActiveWorkbook variable.

Comment: The test you've implemented will work great! +1 for that, now it should solve the suspected problem as advertised.  For the userform_Initialize, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/initialize-event) for more information.  To get to it manually, in Excel's Visual Basic Editor, Insert -> UserForm -> double-click anywhere on the blank gray of the userform window and that will open the userform's code at the `UserForm_Click` event -> Use the drop-down in the upper-right to change from `Click` to `Initialize` -> You're now in the `Userform_Initialize` sub

Comment: For a brief introduction on userforms, here is a good tutorial: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/userform.html

Comment: Thanks for the vote :P If I understand it well, the form get Initialisation when called. It is possible to put variable assignments in that specific sub. Ok, nice !

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but my guess is that it was downvoted because no code was provided in the original question.  Without code to troubleshoot, all we can really do is speculate, and speculation is often a waste of both the asker's and the answerer's time.

Comment: Thank you everyone. That was the exact problem. I was pointing the form to the sheet in all references as apposed to the workbook and then the sheet. Thank you to everyone who helped me. I really appreciate the time you took to answer. Thank you.

Comment: Well thanks for your reply. @nizzlebizzle You're welcome. Can you please mark the answer as right ? To tigeravatar : yes I thought so, reading Mats mud comment again :)